# TSQL parameter problems

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters

I'm pretty new to SSRS reporting so bear with me.

When I run the report, the MONTH parameter has a problem if I select only one value from the multiple selections but if I select multiple values it works!

Anybody got any ideas as to why this is the case?

The error message says "An error has occurred during report processing (rsProcessingAborted)".

See TSQL coding below.

Thanks!

```
SELECT
rTranslog.[Month]
,rTranslog.Site
,rTranslog.NSVCode
,REPLACE(rProduct.LabelDescription, '!', ' ') AS [Drug] 
,SUM(rTranslog.Qty) AS [Quantity]
,SUM(rTranslog.Cost/100) AS [CostIncVAT]
,SUM(rTranslog.CostExTax/100) AS [CostExVAT]
,rSpecialty.Description AS [SpecialtyDescription]
,rSpecialty.DirectorateCode
,rSpecialty.DivisionCode
,rSpecialty.CostCentre

FROM
rTranslog
INNER JOIN rProduct
ON rTranslog.NSVCode = rProduct.NSVCode
INNER JOIN rSpecialty
ON rTranslog.Specialty = rSpecialty.SpecialtyCode

GROUP BY rTranslog.Month, rTranslog.Site, rTranslog.NSVCode, 
rTranslog.Specialty, rSpecialty.Description, rSpecialty.DirectorateCode, 
rSpecialty.DivisionCode, rSpecialty.CostCentre, 
REPLACE(rProduct.LabelDescription, '!', ' ')

HAVING Month IN (@Month) AND rSpecialty.Description IN 
(@SpecialtyDescription) AND Site IN (@Site)

ORDER BY CostIncVAT DESC;
```

Comment: Can you share the content of the report file (*.rdl, *.rdlc)?

Comment: I suspect the the T-SQL is fine. It looks OK assuming this is being run in the dataset directly (i.e. not a stored proc). To test, copy the report and strip everything in the design (tables, matricies, textboxes etc.) and just put a simple table in with now grouping etc. I expect this will work. If it does then check the output for errors in your original report. If you can;t see anything wrong there, post the report design.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your support. I've managed to work out there was a problem with the dataset properties to do with the parameters. For some reason there was some duplication going on. Many thanks for your thoughts